# Добавление записей в инфоблок Bitrix

Tags: javascript, битрикс, битрикс24

Собственно вопрос заключается в том, как добавить запись в инфоблок после отработки сткрипта
Сам скрипт добавляет кэшбэк на внутренний счет пользователя и нужно вести запись начислений кэшбэка с указанием Дата/Время, Сумма заказа, ID заказа, ID пользователя.

```
<?php


AddEventHandler("sale", "OnSaleStatusOrder", "UpdatekBonus");
// AddEventHandler("sale", "OnSaleCancelOrder", "CanceUpdateAccountBonus");

function UpdatekBonus($orderId, $statusId)
{
    $order = CSaleOrder::GetByID($orderId);
    $price = $order['PRICE'];
    
    if ($price >= 2000 && $price <= 5000) { 
        $cashbackPercent = 10; 
    } elseif ($price >= 1000 && $price < 1990) {
        $cashbackPercent = 5;
    } else {
        return; 
    } 
    
    if ($statusId == "F" && $order['CANCELED'] == "N") {
        // Заказ выполнен, начисление кэшбэка
        $sumBonus = $order['PRICE'] * $cashbackPercent / 100;
        $info = "Бонус за оплату заказа в размере $orderId от заказа";
        CSaleUserAccount::UpdateAccount($order['USER_ID'], $sumBonus, "RUB", $info, $orderId);


        CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
        $el = new CIBlockElement;

        $PROP = array();       // здесь у нас будут храниться свойства

        $PROP['SUM'] = $sumBonus;  
        $PROP['ORDER_ID'] = $orderId;        
        $PROP['USER_ID']= $order['USER_ID'];

        $arLoadProductArray = Array(
            "ACTIVE_FROM" => date('d.m.Y H:i:s'), // обязательно нужно указать дату начала активности элемента
            "ORDER_ID" => $orderId, // указываем какой пользователь добавил элемент
            "USER_ID"   => $order['USER_ID'],
            "SUM"       => $sumBonus,
            "IBLOCK_ID" => 4,              //  собственно сам id блока куда будем добавлять новый элемент
            "PROPERTY_VALUES"=> $PROP,  // Добавим нашему элементу заданные свойства
        );
        
        if($newElement = $el->Add($arLoadProductArray))  // с помощью Add добавляем новый элемент
        echo "ID Нового элемента: ".$newElement;      
        else    
        echo "Error: ".$el->LAST_ERROR;


    } elseif ($statusId == "N" && $order['CANCELED'] == "Y") {
        // Заказ отменен, снятие кэшбэка
        $sumBonus = -($order['PRICE'] * $cashbackPercent / 100);
        $info = "Снятие денег со счета в связи с отменой оплаты в размере $orderId от заказа";
        CSaleUserAccount::UpdateAccount($order['USER_ID'], $sumBonus, "RUB", $info, $orderId);
    }
}
?>
```